# Ruby: how to split 365 lines of values by month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Say you have a CSV file with 365 lines corresponding to 365 days in the year. How can I split these lines by month knowing that the number of days in February to be 28?

Example:

```
1;10
2;12.4
3;45.0
...
365;12.8
```

to be able to build something like that:

```
month;day;value
1;1;10
1;2;12.4
1;3;45.0
...
//till the 31 because January has 31 days
1;31;110

// February values start below for 28 next lines
2;32;12.0
2;33;56.0
...
//till the 59 because 31 (days in January) + 28 (days in February) = 59
// MArch values start below for the next 31 lines
3;60;1.23
...
etc.
//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# produce test data
lines = (1..365).to_a.map{ |i| "#{i}; #{rand(100)}"}

# store days per month in a helper array...
months = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
# and check
months.sum
=> 365

# map months to slices of lines
# use the bang-version of slice to make sure
# you start at 0 in each iteration
lines_by_month = months.map{ |no_days| lines.slice!(0, no_days) }

# make sure that lines is empty
lines
=> []

# check element 0
lines_by_month[0]
=> ["1; 29",
    "2; 44",
    "3; 96", ...

# iterate through months
lines_by_month.each_with_index do |lines, i|
  # and iterate through lines
  lines.map! do |line|
    # and use the index to pre-pend the month index to each line
    "#{i+1}; #{line}"
  end
end

# check month 1
lines_by_month[0]
=> ["1; 1; 29",
    "1; 2; 44",
    "1; 3; 96",
    "1; 4; 84", ...

# check month 2
lines_by_month[1]
=> ["2; 32; 17",
    "2; 33; 47",
    "2; 34; 74", ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. A question though about `# make sure that lines is empty: lines #=> []` what seems to be wrong because you initialized it to have 365 on the very 1st line. Am I missing smth?

Comment: @belgoros slice! acutally removes the retrieved elements from the caller. Therefore, after twelve calls with each call removing the corresponding number of days, all lines should have been removed. This is what should be tested.

Comment: The reason for using the bang-version is that this way you don't have to keep track of the starting index for the next slice. Since slice! removes the retrieved elements, the starting index of the next call to slice! will be 0 automatically!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to convert the day to a date, then extract the month and month day. The year/day of year notation is also called an [ordinal date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date). For example the date of today (`2021-05-06`) could also be written as `2021-126` (days are zero padded if there are less then 3 digits, `2021-02-02` is written as `2021-033`).

To convert your day of the year, to a month/day of month notation you could use [`Date.ordinal(year, day_of_year)`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-ordinal). Depending on the amount of lines you can use either a normal year or leap year.

```rb
yday_csv = <<~CSV
  1;10
  2;12.4
  3;45.0
  365;12.8
CSV

mday_csv = CSV.generate(col_sep: ';') do |csv|
  csv << ['month', 'day', 'value']

  lines = CSV.parse(yday_csv, col_sep: ';', converters: :integer)
  year = lines.size <= 365 ? 2021 : 2020 # normal year or leap year

  lines.map { |yday, value| [Date.ordinal(year, yday), value] }
       .map { |date, value| [date.month, date.mday, value] }
       .each { |row| csv << row }
end

puts mday_csv
```

```
month;day;value
1;1;10
1;2;12.4
1;3;45.0
12;31;12.8
```

Instead of passing `converters: :integer` to the CSV parser you could also leave it as string, then call [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) before passing it to `Date.ordinal`.

If you want to keep using the day of the year for the output change `date.mday` to `date.yday`.

You can use [`CSV.open`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) to directly read/write to files instead of using a variable.

For those not using Rails you need to [`require 'csv'`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) and [`require 'date'`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let's first construct such a file.

```
require 'csv'

FNAME = 'csv_data'

line = 0
CSV.open(FNAME, "wb", col_sep: ';') do |csv|
  (1..365).each { |line| csv << [line, line.to_f] }
end
```

and confirm what was written.

```
puts File.read(FNAME)
1;1.0
2;2.0
...
365;365.0
```

We can now obtain the desired information. The first step is to specify the number of days per month.

```
days_by_month = {
  'Jan'=>31, 'Feb'=>28, 'Mar'=>31, 'Apr'=>30, 'May'=>31, 'June'=>30,
  'Jul'=>31, 'Aug'=>31, 'Sep'=>30, 'Oct'=>31, 'Nov'=>30, 'Dec'=>31
}        

days_in_year = CSV.foreach(FNAME).count
  #=> 365
```

Adjust if it's a leap year.

```
days_by_month['Feb'] = 29 if days_in_year == 366
```

As expected,

```
days_by_month['Feb']
  #=> 28
```

Now let's compute cumulative numbers of days from the beginning of the year, by month.

```
tot = 0
cum_days_per_year = days_by_month.map { |mon,days| [mon, tot += days] }.to_h
  #=> {"Jan"=>31, "Feb"=>59, "Mar"=>90, "Apr"=>120, "May"=>151, "June"=>181,
  #    "Jul"=>212, "Aug"=>243, "Sep"=>273, "Oct"=>304, "Nov"=>334, "Dec"=>365}
```

We can now read the file and tally the desired information in a convenient form.

```
CSV.foreach(FNAME, col_sep: ';', converters: [:integer, :float])
   .with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |csv,h|
      mon = cum_days_per_year.find { |_,cum| csv[0] <= cum }.first
      h[mon] << csv[1]
    end
  #=> {"Jan"=>[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0,
  #            11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0,
  #            21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0],
  #    "Feb"=>[32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0, 41.0, 42.0,
  #            43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0,
  #            54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.0],
  #    ...
  #    "Dec"=>[335.0, 336.0, 337.0, 338.0, 339.0, 340.0, 341.0, 342.0, 343.0, 344.0,
  #            345.0, 346.0, 347.0, 348.0, 349.0, 350.0, 351.0, 352.0, 353.0, 354.0,
  #            355.0, 356.0, 357.0, 358.0, 359.0, 360.0, 361.0, 362.0, 363.0, 364.0,
  #            365.0]}
```

To speed calculations one could replace

```
mon = cum_days_per_year.find { |_,cum| csv[0] <= cum }.first
```

with a binary search, using [Array#bsearch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch).

Note that:

- The lines of the CSV file do not have to be in day-of-year order.
- I used [CSV::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) because that method return an enumerator when no block is present, permitting it to be chained to [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object).
- `converters: [:integer, :float]` *cannot* be replaced by `converters: [:float, :integer]`.
- if `h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }`, then, after adding 31 key-value pairs for `'Jan'` (so `h #=> { 'Jan'=>[1.0, 2.0,...31.0] }`), `h['Feb'] << 32.0` results in `h['Feb'] #=> [32.0]` because `h` does not yet have a key `'Feb'`. Then `h['Feb'] << 33.0` results in `h['Feb'] #=> [32.0, 33.0]` because `h` now has a key `'Feb'`, so the *default proc* does not apply.

Comment: Wow you deciphered all that from the question? I am still trying to process what the desire is that `each.with_index(1)` doesn't solve.